# "unlock badges" -> "earn badges" in tour

Tags: feature-request, badges, tour

The paragraph title "Unlock badges for special achievements" in the tour page seems odd.  You "earn badges".  I suggest that the word "Unlock" be replaced with "Earn" in the site tour pages.

I checked a few online dictionaries and none of them refer to unlocking achievements, badges, or trophies.  They talk about things that are physically locked up or are secret.

Here, it makes sense to unlock privileges but not (to me) badges, because they are neither locked up nor secret.

Comment: The word "unlock" is used quite often with badges, achievements, trophies, etc when referring to gamifying pretty much anything. What makes it so odd when used here?